# Arqade League of Legends group

Tags: discussion, community

> So, this didn't turn out to be one of my best ideas ever.  Call it dead.  I do like @StrixVaria's comment about compiling a glossary of terms and abbreviations, though, and @Raven has helpfully provided a link to our current one.

## Problem

As many of us know, we will be hosting another League of Legends contest/sponsorship this weekend.  Many of our users have tried LoL, and almost invariably, we have found the community extremely hostile and rabid, and subsequently no longer play.  This has left our site lacking expertise in not only answering these questions, but also unable to properly vet and comprehend what those questions might be asking.  I for one, especially, am not up on the lingo and jargon used by the LoL community.

Continuing to play the game, however, exposes us to that same hostile community, and results in a bad experience for us, win or lose.

## Solution

I propose that we form a group of people who are willing to play LoL, to last at least the weekend.  We can form teams easier (with enough people), and ensure we don't have a bad experience that would result from random teaming.

We already have a mumble server, so we can use that to help co-ordinate ourselves, too!

---

I realize this sounds fairly elitest, but I, for one, *really* don't want to play with the LoL community at large.  I believe there are others here who would be receptive to this.

Thoughts?  Suggestions?

Comment: Is playing in an isolated group for a small amount of time really going to help you comprehend questions full of lingo and jargon?

Comment: Wasn't LoL just recently removed from being the Saturday Game On! game due to lack of interest??

Comment: While I appreciate the spirit of this, I kind of have to agree with @bwarner here. We already do have a very small regular group, a [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2348/summoners-rift) that's rarely frequented, as well as a chatroom in LoL itself (info in the linked chat's description). I'm not sure I understand how this would help deal with the question influx.

Comment: Instead, we should have some kind of wiki glossary of LoL terms and lingo to help normal users comprehend the influx of questions.

Comment: @StrixVaria I like this idea.  Probably better than making a group.

Comment: I think this is a bit of a manufactured problem. Don't be so quick to discount [these folks](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/218/league-of-legends?userid=3015).

Comment: @RavenDreamer Even though that URL says League of Legends, it actually goes to Mass Effect 3. Huh?

Comment: @StrixVaria odd. Fixed. I think.

Answer (score 5):

I highly doubt the average League of Legends player is demonstrably worse than any other hostile player from Call of Duty, Team Fortress 2, or World of Warcraft. Some people are jerks, sure; *every* community has its problem players. But when you engender a negative attitude by assuming *everyone* remotely associated with the game is a jerk, you're setting yourself up for failure.

Considering that [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) is the 6th most popular tag on our site (even before the first LoL promotion), I doubt the blanket statement bemoaning our lack of experts is demonstrably true, either.

Now, beneath your arrogant self-righteousness, you do make one point I agree with: **League of Legends has lots of lingo and game-specific terminology** that can make it seem arcane to someone familiar with the game.

So what do you do? You talk about it. Bring potential problem questions up in chat, talk it over with other users. You don't need to know the game to fix spelling and grammar. Beyond that, you really don't have many other options, as playing a few games isn't going to make you magically learn all the ins and outs before the competition.

If one of the site's acknowledged [LoL answerers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/218/league-of-legends) (And I'm sure we have more folks who have the requisite knowledge, but lack the tag badge, yet) isn't around to help you sort AP from AD, we actually have a question explicitly made regarding common terms and abbreviations:

[What do those abbreviations mean in LoL?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/32299/336)

Finally, when in doubt, don't act. If you don't know, don't try and fix it. Stackexchange doesn't expect everyone to be an expert on everything, and is designed to be community-centered.

Lead by example. Leave (polite!) comments asking for clarification or suggestion improvements. Try to work *with* the OP, instead of assuming hostility from them. You just might be surprised at the nice reasonable people out there in the LoL community once you stop assuming they don't exist.

Comment: Mm.  You have a point, though I don't agree with the arrogant self-righteousness comment.  Part of it is my fault that I didn't link any context at all.  I would just like to point out that two members who were in chat when we were discussing this [agree](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5324975#5324975) [with](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5325292#5325292) me that the LoL community is extremely unfriendly, and they play(ed) it far more than I did.  So, I DO have a basis beyond my own experience where I'm coming from.

Comment: You haven't answered 3x, since you've only answered 86 - the next most prolific is already at 57, while the next one on the ranking is at 35. I *can* think of a community in which the *average* player is in fact demonstrably more crude than any of those names, but that's why we don't let that community see the light of day.

Comment: @GraceNote You're right of course. I read combined upvotes as answers. I thought it a bit odd that I'd answered over 600 LoL questions without noticing...

Answer (score 0):

Just let supply and demand adjust itself.

Suppose there are more questions for LoL than people willing or able to answer, then:

- The OP might learn the answers through other means and if he really cares about Arqade he will post an answer himself. He will supply the demand he has created.
- Eventually a really good LoL player might join the community and answer all those questions.

IMHO there is no value in forcing someone to play a game he dislikes, even if it is only the community that is bugging him. Games are all about fun!

Here is another thing to think about:

If those people are so evil and hostile as you claim they are, they might harm the Arqade community. It might be good that this site lacks this LoL expertise, so they do not pollute this site.

Otherwise your statement is false in the first place.

Comment: Who said anything about forcing?  The whole point of this was to present an idea, and see what the community thought.  Obviously, they don't like it.

Comment: I had the impression you wanted to force yourself to play the game. My apologies if this is not the case.

Comment: "Eventually a really good LoL player might join the community and answer all those questions." ow, my pride, have some sympathy for us existing decentish LoL players.

Comment: @RapidQA I would comment as well, but since I only have 3 wins against actual humans, I feel I have no pride to wound. =P

Comment: @RapidQA Are we meaning to infer that Elo is like reputation for LoL? ;)

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh I hope not, cause my elo-rep keeps going down =P

Comment: @RapidQA Well god, quit <s>feeding</s> posting bad answers then, jeez. :P